# Как превратить boolean массив в массив String

Tags: java

Как превратить boolean массив с элементами к примеру  {true, false} в массив String, заменив при этом true на Yes , false на No. Приравниваю в обычном   for элементы массива bool к String с помощью метода valueOf дальше тупняк.... :)

```
boolean[] values = {true, false,true}; 
//Исходящий массив 
String[] result = new String[values.length]; 
// Создаю такой же по размеру Стрингвый 
String Yes = "Yes"; 
String No = "No"; 
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
    String y = String.valueOf(values[i]); 
    // присваиваю стрингу "у" трансформ в стринг индекс массива 
    System.out.println(y); 
    // проверяю что все работает 
    // теперь надо наполнить пустой мас result значениями из цикла выше 
    // Туплю 
}
// резалт должен быть {Yes, No, Yes} –
```

ПыСы в этом деле новичок. Вроде и теорию читал по несколько раз, где то пробел.

Comment: Что значит приравниваю булеан к стрингу? Приложи код к вопросу.

Comment: boolean[] values = {true, false,true}; //Исходящий массив 
        String[] result = new String[values.length]; // Создаю такой же по размеру Стрингвый
         String Yes = "Yes"; 
         String No = "No";
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        String y = String.valueOf(values[i]); // присваиваю стрингу "у" трансформ в стринг индекс массива System.out.println(y); // проверяю что все работает 
        // теперь надо наполнить пустой мас result значениями из цикла выше
        // Туплю
        // резалт должен быть {Yes, No, Yes}

Answer (score 0):

Создаете массив строк, равный по размеру массиву булов
проходите по каждому булевскому элементу,
если  arr[i]==true => записывете в строку[i] yes
Если arr[i]==false False => записываете в строку[i] no

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html), что пишет нам документация.

```
valueOf(String s)
Returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified string.
```

Тоесть если в параметре метода valueOf() прилетает true в строковом выражении ("true"), то тогда на выходе мы получаем истину (true) и соответственно, если указываем отличное от true, например любую строку ("какая-то строка"), то получаем ложь (false).

Для наглядности привожу простенький код, как подсказку:

```
  public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.print("Yer or No? (true/false)?\n");

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String value = scanner.nextLine();
      scanner.close();

      Boolean answer = Boolean.valueOf(value);

      if (answer) {
          System.out.println("Yes");
      } else {
          System.out.println("No");
      }
   }
}
```

Поиграйся с кодом. Он не сложный. Думаю все интуитивно понятно. Если возникнут вопросы, пиши.